# How to correctly get TFS changeset number into Project Version field of SonarScanner on Jenkins?

Tags: jenkins, sonarqube, tfvc, sonarscanner

We are running Jenkins as our build server and on-prem TFS as our source control. We are using SonarScanner for MSBuild step before the build, and one of the fields which can be populated is "project Version". The value in this field will tag the sonar analysis with the version.

[image]

I have tried the following values:

- `$TFS_CHANGESET`
- `${TFS_CHANGESET}`
- `${ENV,var="TFS_CHANGESET"}`

but unfortunately I just get the literal text that is put in, not an evaluation of the environment variable.

Is there a way to get the actual environment variable evaluated and it's value used instead? The sonarqube scanner documentation does not appear to provide information on how to use environment variables, and the various posts I have read, leading to the values I have tried do not appear to work either!

[image]

Ref:
https://community.sonarsource.com/t/expand-environment-variables-in-sonarqube-scanner-for-jenkins/4711

Answer (score 1):

> How to correctly get TFS changeset number into Project Version field of SonarScanner on Jenkins?

If you are using the default way to download your code from Azure DevOps Server by through the usage of the Source Code Management Tab, it seems we could not configure it to download the source code by a particular changeset number.

To resolve this issue, you could use Windows batch command to get the latest source code:

```
%TFS% workspaces -format:brief -server:{your-tfs-team-project-collection-url}
%TFS% workspace -new Hudson-%JOB_NAME%-MASTER;{your-domain-user-name} -noprompt -server:{your-tfs-team-project-collection-url}
%TFS% workfold -map $/{tfs-path-to-your-sln} C:\Jenkins\jobs\%JOB_NAME%\workspace\ -workspace:Hudson-%JOB_NAME%-MASTER -server:{your-tfs-team-project-collection-url}
%TFS% get $/{tfs-path-to-your-sln} -force -recursive -noprompt
%TFS% history $/{tfs-path-to-your-sln} -recursive -stopafter:1 -noprompt -format:brief -server:{your-tfs-team-project-collection-url}
```

Please check the document [Jenkins: Get Source Code By Specific TFS Changeset](https://dzone.com/articles/jenkins-get-source-code-by-specific-tfs-changeset-1) for some more details.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you, but not using "Azure DevOps Server"